# Why I'm getting the error :ReferenceError: status is not defined when using body-phraser?

Tags: node.js, body-parser

I'm new to node js and when using body-phraser I'm getting the error: *`ReferenceError: status is not defined`*. The code is shown below.
when a json is posted to the *localhost:3000/* products the following error seems to be rising but i can't figure out why this happens. Does the reference error occur due to an bug in my code:
The error I get is:

```
ReferenceError: status is not defined
    at app.use (/home/marper96/Desktop/node/node-rest-shop/app.js:22:5)
    at Layer.handle_error (/home/marper96/Desktop/node/node-rest-shop/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:71:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/marper96/Desktop/node/node-rest-shop/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:315:13)
    at /home/marper96/Desktop/node/node-rest-shop/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/marper96/Desktop/node/node-rest-shop/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/marper96/Desktop/node/node-rest-shop/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Layer.handle_error (/home/marper96/Desktop/node/node-rest-shop/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:67:12)
    at trim_prefix (/home/marper96/Desktop/node/node-rest-shop/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:315:13)
    at /home/marper96/Desktop/node/node-rest-shop/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/marper96/Desktop/node/node-rest-shop/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
```

The code I'm using:

```
router.post('/',(req,res,next) =>{
    const product ={
        name :req.body.name,
        price :req.body.price
    };
    res.status(201).json({
        messsage:'Handelling post requests to /products',
        createdproduct:product
    });
});

module.exports =router;
```

Comment: Could show us your express configuration?

Comment: in the app.js file

Comment: in the app.js file const express =require('express');
const app =express();
const morgan =require('morgan');
const productRoute=require('./api/routes/product');
const orderRoute =require('./api/routes/orders');
const bodyParser =require('body-parser');
do we need to manually call the  require('body-parser') for each of the routes?

Answer (score 0):

Please add body-parsor to the router like below lines,

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
router.use(bodyParser.json());
```

You have to add body-parser to the middle-ware with 'use' method like above and your code,

```js
router.post('/',(req,res,next) =>{
    const product ={
        name :req.body.name,
        price :req.body.price
    };
    res.status(201).json({
        messsage:'Handelling post requests to /products',
        createdproduct:product
    });
});
```